# Vertically align text to the bottom of the box?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, uitextposition

I made box and I set line-height, the text is automatically vertically center. Is there a way or any kind of trick to set the text on the bottom of the box?

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
 }

<div>FoxRox</div>
```

Comment: You could change the line height to something around 180px. Vertical-align is only for inline elements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**2020 Update**

You can use CSS grid, flexbox or the original method with `line-height`:

```css
body { display: flex } /* just to prettify */

div {
  margin: .5em;
  width: 6.25em; height: 6.25em;
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-content: end;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center
}

.lh { line-height: 11.5 /* 6.25*2 - 1.5 */ }
```

```html
<div class='grid'>Hello</div>

<div class='flex'>Hello</div>

<div class='lh'>Hello</div>
```

---

Setting the `height` of the `div` and the `line-height` of the text to the same value, `100px` in your case, is a method of vertically centering the text within the `div`. That's the problem.

The solution is to change `line-height` to twice the height minus the size of the text and remove useless `vertical-align`.

Comment: That's *part of* the problem. The content has to be inside an `inline-block` for `vertical-align` to work.

Comment: I liked how you solved it by just using `line-height`. Smart! thnx a lot, saved me a lot of markup!

Comment: Can only imagine what wisdom that broken link once might have contained

Comment: Hi @Ana, Can you please retrieve you thoughts that you pasted into the broken link. An up-voted answer going to waste right now.

Answer (score 9):

Enclose the text in a `p` tag with `display:inline-block`. Set `vertical-align` to the `p` element.

```
<div>
    <p>FoxRox</p>
</div>​

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
 }
p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -80px;
}
​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfx92/6/)**

Answer (score 5):

You could set display to table-cell, try this CSS for example.

```
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kawwr/

Comment: Spot on, and not as complicated as the other answers would lead you to believe

Comment: This won't work if the `position` is defined. It works only with position relative.

Answer (score 2):

You could check out my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116514/682480.

Here is the ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/7BBqC/)*** for the above answer.

---

The trick is to use `display: table-cell` on the outer container. That way you can use the `vertical-align: bottom` and `display: inline-block;` on the div.