# Logo and text next to it at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to make a header where i have a logo positioned left and text next to that logo (on the right side of the logo) but i want the text to appear at the bottom of the image not at the top. How would i achieve that?

I tried with making the header div relative and the slogan div absolute but then the text is written over the image...

my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container header">
<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="slogan">
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

and css:

```
 body{
        maring:0 auto;
    }

    .logo{
        float:left;
    }

    .slogan{
        float:left;
    }
```

Here is a image of what i want to achieve:
[image: Image of what i want]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text to the bottom of the box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760088/vertically-align-text-to-the-bottom-of-the-box)

Comment: em, no. Did you even read what i want to achieve?

Comment: Yep, and it's pretty much the same. The only difference is the logo which should not be a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/dLrndyyh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish for dynamic resizing let me suggest a flexbox alternative:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.slogan {
  /* float: left; */
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=100×100&w=100&h=100" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="slogan">
    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to give your slogan a top margin:

```
.slogan{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: margins are not good for responsive design... so not really something i can do

Comment: @mheonyae I'm actually genuinely curious why you think that is the case? Do you have a reference?

Comment: you realize that on different screen the image is different size? means the margin has to be different as well to get what i want to achieve

Comment: @mheonyae ah, and you can't use em or %?