# How snuggle DIV to bottom side

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a block:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="image">
        <span class="grow">4</span>
        <img src="images/rate_doctor_photo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rate" style="background:#00a7ff">
        <div class="ln"></div>
        <span>Алексей Романов Олегович</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How shuggle block with class="image" to block with class="rate"
Remark: bloks class="rate" have different height always

Comment: could you make a mockup image of what you're trying to accomplish, I know english is probably not your first language, but I cannot understand you at all right now.

Comment: Is snuggle a technical term?

Comment: Is something like this what you want? Your question was a bit confusing to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116423/how-to-vertically-align-floating-divs-to-the-bottom If not, mind re-wording your question?

Comment: Who cares, snuggling is always nice

Comment: Smile) suggling = position down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like so:

```
.image,
.rate{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/7xjTC/

Comment: Somebody can help me?