# Vertical align input elements with different size label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align form-group vertically at the bottom whenever I've some label with more than one line.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9vtsojqg/3/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div id="small" class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">normal label</label>
            <input class="form-control"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">example of a huge label</label>
            <input class="form-control"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way I found to align the elements vertically was adding margin-top to the form-groups with one line label

```
#small{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

but with the grid system that could vary.
How can I align the elements based on the biggest (most lines occupied) label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just found the solution I was looking for in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929313/2417978), so using:

```
.row{
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-flow: row nowrap; /* is default: columns along the main-axis (row) and no wrapping to next lines */
  align-items: flex-end; /* bottom */
```

I achieve what I was looking for. ex.: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vtsojqg/6/)

**Update:** This will change the normal behavior of the class *row* so I suggest that this properties should be use with some caution. In my case I'll use this in *form .row* or assign another class to this elements.
Other solutions or comments related to this solution are appreciated.

**Update 2:** New version after the heads up from *[Gorostas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266992/gorostas)* http://jsfiddle.net/9vtsojqg/8/

```
form .row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -ms-flex-direction: row nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  -ms-flex-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I think this way it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/9vtsojqg/8/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can wrapp all in table like this

http://jsfiddle.net/9vtsojqg/4/

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">normal label</label></td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">example of a huge label that have so many text, and so much text</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control"></input></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control"></input></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but if possible I would like to keep using the grid system.

Comment: Chnaged behavior of your elements, like display:table, display:table-cell

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div id="small" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">normal label</label>
                <input class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">example of a huge label</label>
                <input class="form-control"></input>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Is that what you mean ?