# Bottom alignment

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs, one is left floated with bigger font size and the other one is right floated with smaller fonts. I want to align the smaller fonted DIV to the bottom aligned with the bigger sized text. Not able to achieve it.

and the css

```
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}

.floatRight {
    float: right;
}

.font12 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floatLeft">Activity</div>
<div class="floatRight font12 "><a href="javascript:void(0);">View timeline / Filter activities</a></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to put your CSS.

Comment: Don't `float`. Use Flexbox. You can 'float' anything anywhere with Flexbox. It's complex. Take your time to learn it. It's worth it. [This might be useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116423/how-to-vertically-align-floating-divs-to-the-bottom/16929313#16929313)

Comment: @rudie using flexbox might be a tricky thing because you have to take care of handling it for all the different browsers and versions. Using `inline-block` is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @akshay You're right. In this case, Flexbox is too tricky.

Comment: @nicael CSS :

.floatLeft{float: left;}
.floatRight{float: right;}
.font12{font-size: 12px;}

default font of the page is 16px.

Comment: @akshay

this approach works, but here the second DIV comes just next to the first one. I want both of them aligned to left and right as I have coded.

Comment: @maulik doesn't my answer now solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Answer changed to allow for float as per your request.

Please see [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xaj1fdoz/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="big">Activity</div>

<div class="small"> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">View timeline / Filter activities
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big {
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em
}
.small {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    top: 13px;
}
```

Comment: this approach works, but here the second DIV comes just next to the first one. I want both of them aligned to left and right as I have coded.

Comment: this solution will wrap the smaller div below the `.big` div when the screen size is smaller

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo page**](https://jsfiddle.net/uzonc2fo/2/)

### CSS needed:

```
.big {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /* just for demo: */
    font-size: 2em;
    height:200px; 
    background:#FADDFF;
}

.small {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /* just for demo: */
    font-size: 1em;
    background:#D2E9F7;
    height:120px;
}
```

so making the two elements `inline-block` displayed, and `vertical-align` with value of `bottom`, they will be on the same level, and they're line of reference will be the bottom of them both

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the above response, you can use display: table-cell to fit both div's to the same height:

```css
.floatLeft {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.floatRight {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floatLeft">Activity</div>
<div class="floatRight font12 "><a href="javascript:void(0);">View timeline / Filter activities</a></div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3m72kqh/

Comment: this approach works, but text of both the divs can change, in that case fixing width of them is not a good idea. And I want both of them aligned to left and right as I have coded.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: [Solution in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aksris/05qegnkw/)

Here is a solution with `inline-block` :

```
.big {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em
}
.small {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1em
}
a {
    float:right;
}
```